# Download recursively with wget

Tags: wget

I have a problem with the following wget command:

`wget -nd -r -l 10 http://web.archive.org/web/20110726051510/http://feedparser.org/docs/`

It should download recursively all of the linked documents on the original web but it downloads only two files (`index.html` and `robots.txt`).

How can I achieve recursive download of [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726051510/http://feedparser.org/docs/) web?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`wget` by default honours the [robots.txt  standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/) for crawling pages, just like search engines do, and for archive.org, it disallows the entire /web/ subdirectory.
To override, use `-e robots=off`,

```
wget -nd -r -l 10 -e robots=off http://web.archive.org/web/20110726051510/http://feedparser.org/docs/
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there some option to store every link only once? Maybe I should decrease `10` to lower number, but it's hard to guess. Now there is a file `introduction.html`, `introduction.html.1`, `introduction.html.2` and I rather ended the process.

Comment: And the links are directing to the web. Is the `--mirror` option for the links to direct to the filesystem?

Comment: @xralf: well, you are using `-nd`, so different `index.html`s are put in the same directory, and without `-k`, you'll not get rewriting of the links.

Answer (score 17):

```
$ wget --random-wait -r -p -e robots=off -U Mozilla \
    http://web.archive.org/web/20110726051510/http://feedparser.org/docs/
```

Downloads recursively the content of the url.

```
--random-wait - wait between 0.5 to 1.5 seconds between requests.
-r - turn on recursive retrieving.
-e robots=off - ignore robots.txt.
-U Mozilla - set the "User-Agent" header to "Mozilla". Though a better choice is a real User-Agent like "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)".
```

Some other useful options are:

```
--limit-rate=20k - limits download speed to 20kbps.
-o logfile.txt - log the downloads.
-l 0 - remove recursion depth (which is 5 by default).
--wait=1h - be sneaky, download one file every hour.
```

Comment: `-l 0 - remove recursion depth (which is 5 by default)` +1

Comment: Specifying -U Mozilla  skipped "Are you a robot question"