# Trying to get a dynamic page with wget without success

Tags: wget, html

I am using this command to get a page and all its images and javascripts on iTunes with wget. All I want is this page and all its images and scripts.

```
 wget -kKErpNF --no-check-certificate --html-extension  -nd -A jpg,jpeg,png,js  -nH https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/megamilhoes-megasena-gerador/id854897303?mt=12
```

The command is working almost well but it is not saving the page itself because the page is dynamic and built in the browser. There is no html/html extension on the page. How do I get that?

`--html-extension` is causing no effect. I am on OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple by default rejects the html file download. I used the commands that you had specified in my machine. If you carefully look at the output, you will get something like this.

```
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2014-05-24 10:43:50--  https://itunes.apple.com/robots.txt
Connecting to itunes.apple.com|23.206.210.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 234 [text/plain]
Saving to: `robots.txt'
```

So as per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25340/download-recursively-with-wget) answer we can ignore the *robots.txt* file by using `-e robots=off` in the command.

> `Wget` by default honours the [robots.txt  standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/) for crawling
>   pages, just like search engines do, and for archive.org, it disallows
>   the entire /web/ subdirectory. To override, use `-e robots= off`,

So, I modified your command to add `-e robots= off` and when I ran the command again, I got the below output.

```
Connecting to itunes.apple.com|23.204.162.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `id854897303?mt=12.html'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                  ] 33,456      --.-K/s   in 0.001s  

2014-05-24 10:48:38 (30.1 MB/s) - `id854897303?mt=12.html' saved [33456]

Removing id854897303?mt=12.html since it should be rejected.
```

As you can see, the file download is prevented by apple and we cannot do anything about it.

**EDIT**: Even without `-e robots=off`, we are not able to download the html file. It is saying rejected with your original wget too. So, I suspect apple is disallowing `wget` downloads.

Comment: thru finder you can see that wget generates a HTML file for a brief period of time then deletes that.

Comment: Yeah, I see it. I am afraid that you will not be able to download the contents.

Comment: +1 If Apple is disallowing wget specifically (there are sites which do), you might get different results by experimenting with the `--user-agent` switch, to trick the server into believing this is a normal web browser.