# I'm unable to get wget to succesfully be recursive while mirroring a blog

Tags: wget

I want to make an offline mirror of this blog: http://blogs.gamefilia.com/lord-areg

I'm using:

```
wget --recursive --level=0 --span-hosts --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --no-parent -e robots=off --wait=4 --random-wait --adjust-extension --no-check-certificate --user-agent=Mozilla http://blogs.gamefilia.com/lord-areg/‍
```

But I do only get `index.html`, can't get any of the subdirectories... And I need all of them

For example:

```
lord-areg/15-01-2012/47781/boveda-de-articulos-de-silent-hill

lord-areg/01-02-2012/48151/eddie-dombrowski-la-pistola-y-la-pizza-misteriosa
```

etc.

Comment: You could start by *removing* some options; [here is a command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25353/135943) that worked for someone else.  Then once you have it working, add options to adjust it to your preferences.

Comment: Hello @Wildcard  It didn't work (same results, just index.html was downloaded), but thanks for your answer. Anyways, I don't think start removing options could help, since I've just tried `wget --recursive -e robots=off --no-parent http://blogs.gamefilia.com/lord-areg/‍` and it isn't working either.

Comment: Try again without the trailing `/`.  The initial redirection makes a difference (for me) but I haven't yet worked out why.

Comment: Unfortunately, If I try without the trailing `‍/`‍ wget tries to mirror the entire gamefilia site, and it's huge... I'm sure there is a way to download individual blogs, but I just can't figure it out. Thank you very much anyways.

Comment: Use `-I lord-areg` as well as omitting the trailing `/`.  See the Note under `--no-parent` in the [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits).

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks @JigglyNaga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running with `-d` shows what's going on:

```
Location: http://blogs.gamefilia.com/lord-areg [following]
    ....
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://blogs.gamefilia.com/lord-areg".
Going to "" would escape "lord-areg" with no_parent on.
Decided NOT to load it.
Redirection "http://blogs.gamefilia.com/lord-areg" failed the test.
```

The redirected page was outside the area specified, so although it was retrieved, its contents aren't followed when recursing.

Removing the final `/` means there's no redirection, but as you found, also means wget doesn't treat `lord-areg` as a directory, and uses the previous `/`, so the whole site matches:

> Note that, for HTTP (and HTTPS), the trailing slash is very important to ‘--no-parent’. HTTP has no concept of a “directory”—Wget relies on you to indicate what’s a directory and what isn’t. In ‘http://foo/bar/’, Wget will consider ‘bar’ to be a directory, while in ‘http://foo/bar’ (no trailing slash), ‘bar’ will be considered a filename (so ‘--no-parent’ would be meaningless, as its parent is ‘/’).

([4.3 Directory Based Limits](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits))

So you need to restrict the results in some other manner.  `-I lord-areg` nearly works, but will skip pages of the form `/lord-areg?page=1`.  To match those too, describe the required URLs in more detail:

```
--accept-regex '^http:\/\/blogs\.gamefilia\.com\/lord-areg[?/]'
```