# Download data in the website(http) recursively with wget

Tags: wget

I cannot download the files correctly in this [website](http://biomet.ucdavis.edu/Evapotranspiration/).

I use the command which is shown in [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25340/download-recursively-with-wget)

```
wget -nd -r -l 10  -e robots=off http://biomet.ucdavis.edu/Evapotranspiration/
```

It can truly download the files,but unfortunately,they are download in a *single* folder,instead of the same structure just like in the website.

What should I do to download all these file in the same structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-nd` in your command means *no-directories*.

You should remove the `-nd` option from your command, and you'll get the same structure just like in the website:

```
wget -r -l 10  -e robots=off http://biomet.ucdavis.edu/Evapotranspiration/
```

[wget man](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

> **2.6 Directory Options**
>
> **‘-nd’ ‘--no-directories’**
>
> *Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively. With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current
>   directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the
>   filenames will get extensions ‘.n’).*